# Python jsons library and serializing a dataclass with optional None values

Tags: python, python-jsons

I noticed some warning messages being printed by my Python code. These are coming from the `jsons` library when trying to perform serializing operations.

```
/home/user/project/.venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/jsons/_common_impl.py:43: UserWarning: Failed to dump attribute "None" of object of type "MyClass2". Reason: 'NoneType' object is not callable. Ignoring the attribute. Use suppress_warning(attribute-not-serialized) or suppress_warnings(True) to turn off this message.
  warnings.warn(msg_, *args, **kwargs)
```

`MyClass2` is just something I have been using to isolate the cause of the error.

```
class MyClass():

    def __init__(self) -> None:
        self.data = None

@dataclass
class MyClass2():
    data: int|None

my_class = MyClass()
my_class_2 = MyClass2(
    data=None,
)

print(
    jsons.dumps(
        my_class,
        strip_privates=True,
    )
)

print(
    jsons.dumps(
        my_class_2,
        strip_privates=True,
    )
)
```

`MyClass` does not produce warnings. `MyClass2` does.

I know how to stop the warning message: Change the type hint from `int|None` to `int`.

```
@dataclass
class MyClass2():
    data: int     # no `|None` here !
```

Why does that work?

If I change the type hint from `int|None`, it will still serialize correctly but the warnings are no longer produced. Serializing `None` also works, even without the option of `None` as a type hint.

Comment: https://github.com/ramonhagenaars/jsons/issues/162

Comment: Ahh, it is a bug?

Comment: Not the downvoter, but it might be a good opportunity to answer your own question with an on-site elaboration of the thread at that link, particularly the "work around"

Comment: @JonSG Sorry but I don't understand what you are asking for

Comment: I think you should put a self-answer in indicating that it is a bug per the link but that there is a workaround per the link here so that if someone else has the issue they can find your answer. I would cite the repo in your answer for good measure as well.

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out by others in the comments, this does indeed appear to be a bug.

As a workaround, I would suggest making the value `Optional`.

```
from typing import Optional

class MyClass:

    data: Optional[int] = None
```